# WPF Mousemove is a noticeable lag

Tags: c#, wpf, mousemove

I am making a UserControl called VolumeScrollBar to control the volume a video player I am working on. Now the problem I am having is when I slide my SwitchPath it moves noticeable slower than my mouse. How can I fix this ?

note: everything is working but the speed.

Also, I am not using the built in sliding bar because I do not like how it looks. So I designed my own  Volume scroll bar in Adobe Illustrator.

here is my XAML code:

```
<Canvas x:Name="VolumeScrollBarCanvas"  Height="21" Width="160" >
    <Path x:Name="Path_7" Width="15" Height="13" Canvas.Left="0.777" Canvas.Top="3.556" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 67.6183,648C 67.5503,648 67.4809,648.019 67.4156,648.061L 62.6556,651.173L 61.3916,652L 55.9996,652C 54.5276,652 53.3329,653.193 53.3329,654.667C 53.3329,656.14 54.5276,657.333 55.9996,657.333L 61.3916,657.333L 62.6556,658.16L 67.4156,661.272C 67.4809,661.315 67.5503,661.333 67.6183,661.333C 67.8169,661.333 67.9996,661.169 67.9996,660.937L 67.9996,654.667L 67.9996,648.395C 67.9996,648.164 67.8169,648 67.6183,648 Z M 66.6663,650.144L 66.6663,654.667L 66.6663,659.189L 63.3863,657.044L 62.1209,656.217L 61.7889,656L 61.3916,656L 55.9996,656C 55.2649,656 54.6663,655.401 54.6663,654.667C 54.6663,653.932 55.2649,653.333 55.9996,653.333L 61.3916,653.333L 61.7889,653.333L 62.1209,653.116L 63.3849,652.289L 66.6663,650.144 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Path x:Name="WhiteBarPath" Width="81" Height="7" Canvas.Left="46.111" Canvas.Top="6.223" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 176.667,657.333L 102,657.333C 100.167,657.333 98.6667,655.833 98.6667,654L 98.6667,654C 98.6667,652.167 100.167,650.667 102,650.667L 176.667,650.667C 178.5,650.667 180,652.167 180,654L 180,654C 180,655.833 178.5,657.333 176.667,657.333 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Path x:Name="Path_8" Width="13" Height="20" Canvas.Left="24.151" Canvas.Top="0.639" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 78.6667,645.333C 77.9893,645.333 77.3347,645.451 76.7067,645.648C 81.5307,646.025 85.3333,650.212 85.3333,655.333C 85.3333,660.455 81.5293,664.641 76.7067,665.019C 77.3347,665.216 77.9893,665.333 78.6667,665.333C 83.0853,665.333 89.3333,660.856 89.3333,655.333C 89.3333,649.811 83.0853,645.333 78.6667,645.333 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Path x:Name="Path_9" Width="9.26" Height="15" Canvas.Left="19.168" Canvas.Top="3.556" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 73.1609,648C 72.6636,648 72.1849,648.085 71.7236,648.231C 75.2609,648.508 78.0503,651.579 78.0503,655.333C 78.0503,659.088 75.2609,662.159 71.7236,662.436C 72.1849,662.581 72.6636,662.667 73.1609,662.667C 76.4009,662.667 80.9836,659.384 80.9836,655.333C 80.9836,651.283 76.4009,648 73.1609,648 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Path x:Name="Path_10" Width="4" Height="5" Canvas.Left="18.11" Canvas.Top="8.266" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 72.4039,652.71C 72.2399,652.71 70.9452,652.756 70.6665,652.81L 70.6665,657.311C 71.0052,657.364 72.3412,657.306 72.4039,657.306C 73.6732,657.306 74.7012,656.276 74.7012,655.007C 74.7012,653.739 73.6732,652.71 72.4039,652.71 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Path x:Name="ColorBarPath" Width="81" Height="7" Canvas.Left="46.111" Canvas.Top="6.223" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF6557FF" Data="F1 M 176.667,657.333L 102,657.333C 100.167,657.333 98.6667,655.833 98.6667,654L 98.6667,654C 98.6667,652.167 100.167,650.667 102,650.667L 176.667,650.667C 178.5,650.667 180,652.167 180,654L 180,654C 180,655.833 178.5,657.333 176.667,657.333 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Ellipse x:Name="SwitchPath"    MouseDown="SwitchPath_MouseDown"  MouseMove="SwitchPath_MouseMove"  Mouse.MouseUp="SwitchPath_MouseUp"  Width="19" Height="19" Canvas.Left="115.444" Canvas.Top="0.889" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Path x:Name="Path_7_Copy" Width="15" Height="13" Canvas.Left="0.777" Canvas.Top="3.556" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 67.6183,648C 67.5503,648 67.4809,648.019 67.4156,648.061L 62.6556,651.173L 61.3916,652L 55.9996,652C 54.5276,652 53.3329,653.193 53.3329,654.667C 53.3329,656.14 54.5276,657.333 55.9996,657.333L 61.3916,657.333L 62.6556,658.16L 67.4156,661.272C 67.4809,661.315 67.5503,661.333 67.6183,661.333C 67.8169,661.333 67.9996,661.169 67.9996,660.937L 67.9996,654.667L 67.9996,648.395C 67.9996,648.164 67.8169,648 67.6183,648 Z M 66.6663,650.144L 66.6663,654.667L 66.6663,659.189L 63.3863,657.044L 62.1209,656.217L 61.7889,656L 61.3916,656L 55.9996,656C 55.2649,656 54.6663,655.401 54.6663,654.667C 54.6663,653.932 55.2649,653.333 55.9996,653.333L 61.3916,653.333L 61.7889,653.333L 62.1209,653.116L 63.3849,652.289L 66.6663,650.144 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Path x:Name="Path_6" Width="13" Height="12" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 61.5899,656.667L 56.0005,656.667C 54.8965,656.667 54.0005,655.769 54.0005,654.667C 54.0005,653.564 54.8965,652.667 56.0005,652.667L 61.5899,652.667L 67.3339,648.912L 67.3339,660.421L 61.5899,656.667 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="1.777" Canvas.Top="4.056"/>
    <TextBlock  x:Name="Displaytxb"  Height="18" Canvas.Left="136.069" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="100" Canvas.Top="1.917" Width="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>

</Canvas>
```

and here is my code behind:

```
    private void ChangeTheVolume(double newVolume)
    {
        if (newVolume < 0 || newVolume > 100) return;

        newVolume = Math.Round(newVolume);
        double tempVolume = (ValumeMaxHigh * newVolume);
        ColorBarPath.Width = tempVolume;

        double pointX = (LocationMaxHigh * newVolume) + 46.11;
        Canvas.SetLeft(SwitchPath, pointX); // set the left position of rectangle to mouse X
        Displaytxb.Text = Convert.ToString(newVolume);

        VolumeOut = Volume;
    }
private void SwitchPath_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        _handToolMove = true;
        SwitchPath.CaptureMouse();
        _startPoint = e.GetPosition(VolumeScrollBarCanvas);
        double mouseCurrentLocation =  Canvas.GetLeft(SwitchPath);
        _mouseDownForHandToolOffSetX = _startPoint.X - mouseCurrentLocation;
    }

    private void SwitchPath_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_handToolMove)
        {
            Point v = e.GetPosition(VolumeScrollBarCanvas);
            Volume = 0.6933 * v.X + 1.24946035807;
        }

    }

    private void SwitchPath_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_handToolMove)
        {
            Point v = e.GetPosition(VolumeScrollBarCanvas);
            Volume = 0.6933 * v.X + 1.25;
            SwitchPath.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            _handToolMove = false;
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        }
       
       
    }
}
    public VolumeScrollBar()
    {
        RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
        InitializeComponent();
      
    }
```

Comment: In WPF, if you don't like the look but want to have the functionality, you can supply your own `ControlTemplate` to the existing control.

Comment: You should re template a slider instead of buildling a control from scratch. This is a re templated slider. https://i.imgur.com/6CsDUhN.png

Comment: I agree you will have an easier time re-templating Slider, but I'm gonna give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you want to learn to do it the hard way. :) That said I don't think the problem is in the speed of the render but rather in your math for computing the new position based on the mouse. You're hard coding a lot of numbers there and I'm not clear why you're calculating the slider position the way you are. If you want to post a full reproducible example so we can see what you're seeing we might be able to steer you right.

Comment: @Peter Moore  the math I am using is y=mx+b. the bar starts at x = 46.11 and the end of the bar is at x = 115.44

Comment: Mkay, well, as best I can tell the amount of movement you're calculating for Canvas.Left is not 1:1 with the amount of mouse movement. In other words it's scaling. That's why it appears slow, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Peter Moore how can I fix it?

Comment: @PeterMoore  here a link to my code : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11oS1QYBqsgsqyKO0GMId0mp5mBCvuZVX?usp=sharing

Comment: You read my mind. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here isn't the speed of the render but just in your geometry calculations. The volume is not scaling 1:1 with the mouse movement. (That is, in terms of y=mx+b, m needs to be 1).

So, this line in `SwitchPath_MouseMove` -

```
  Volume = 0.6933 * v.X + 1.24946035807;
```

Would be better written as

```
  Volume = (v.X - 46.11) / ValumeMaxHigh;
```

That markedly improves things after trying it out with your code.

In English, what we want is the position of the mouse X relative to the left edge of the slider, normalized by the total width of the track. So that means mouse X minus the left offset divided by the total available width - which you hard code in `VolumeMaxHigh` (which seems to be the actual width / 100, so this guarantees volume will always be out of 100).

If you had a much more complex graphic, you would want to use a `RenderTransform` during the mouse move, and set `Canvas.Left` only on the mouse up, but this is simple enough where performance is not the issue.

Anyway, if you were to consider redoing this I might suggest writing a general purpose slider of your own that is not dependent on any particular dimensions but rather learns its dimensions at runtime through `ActualWidth` and the like. The source code for WPF is online, specifically for [Slider](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/b63c69eaf5b58e758765a37bb18064bbc94832ad/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/Slider.cs), which will show you how that would be done. Reproducing existing controls in your own coding style is one of the best ways to learn WPF IMO so I'd encourage it as a learning exercise.

You can almost certainly re-template `Slider` to get what you want too, and if all you want to do is solve the problem at hand and go home that's perfectly fine. But since you put in all this effort already it's worth learning how to do right, as sooner or later you'll come up with a genuine need to write a complex custom control.

Also whether you decide to re-template Slider or make your own, [studying the default template for Slider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/slider-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) will help too.

Answer (score -1):

It might be interesting to give an idea how how I re template the slider for our brass sliders.

I'll miss out the complicated stuff for the brass teardrop since it's not relevent here.

This is a bit of a dirty approach but I don't need a bunch of functionality in a regular slider.

A slider has a track - the container for everything. In that go two repeatbuttons ( or buttons or whatever you wanted actually ) which kind of look like the track but clicking them moves your pointer.

Then there is the pointer itself which is a thumb. A thumb in wpf is something intended to be dragged.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BrassSlider"  TargetType="Slider">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Gray"
                  Stroke="Transparent"
                   StrokeThickness="1"
                   Height="13" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="0,0,4,0">
            <Rectangle.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2"/>
            </Rectangle.Effect>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" 
                   Stroke="Sienna"
                   StrokeThickness="1"
                   Height="14" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="0,0,4,0"
                   Fill="White"
                   >
        </Rectangle>
        <Track Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_Track"   
               >
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderDecreaseButtonPlain}"  Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge" />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderIncreaseButtonPlain}" Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge" />
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource SliderThumb}" Grid.ZIndex="30"  />
            </Track.Thumb>
        </Track>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Thumb, but without any teardrop complicated gubbins.

```
<Style x:Key="SliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Control Template="{StaticResource TearDropPointer}" Height="40" Width="20" >
                    <Control.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect />
                    </Control.Effect>
                </Control>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And one of the buttons.

```
<Style x:Key="SliderDecreaseButtonPlain" TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                        Background="Transparent" 
                        BorderThickness="0" Height="14"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You could easily make those repeatbuttons any shape you like defined by a geometry. Like you have.

Similarly, you can easily make the thumb an ellipse or whatever you fancy.

One other thing is worth mentioning.

When you see a named part in any reference template like that PART_Track above then that is likely used in the code for the control. If you miss any named parts out then there's a fair chance your control will not behave as you expect.

Answer (score -2):

This slow response can happen also with a regular Slider. If this was the case I would recommend using the "Delay" to the binding of the Slider.
In your case we should do something similar : all mouse events should  just keep the mouse point somewhere with no logic and no rendering. Parallelly  , create a timer event to occur every 10 milliseconds (or so.. ) , and make the changes there. This way you can improve the system responsiveness.
The code behind may look as following:

```
        Point _lastPoint;
        Point _lastPointHandled;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick; ;
            timer.Start();
        }
        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_lastPoint != _lastPointHandled)
            {
                // do your things
                _lastPointHandled = _lastPoint;
            }
        }
        private void SwitchPath_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _lastPoint = e.GetPosition(VolumeScrollBarCanvas);
        }

        private void SwitchPath_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            _lastPoint = e.GetPosition(VolumeScrollBarCanvas);

        }
```